# Using grunt to concatenate all vendor javascript files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman, gruntjs

I'm using Yeoman (v1.x) with grunt (v0.4.2) to build an Angular project. The `build` task concatenates all my `app/script` JS files, but it leaves all of my dependency files unconcatenated, so that my built index.html makes these calls:

```
<script src="components/angular-unstable/angular.js"></script>
<script src="components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="components/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
<script src="components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>

<!-- xxxxxbuild:js scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/274baf7d.scripts.js"></script>
```

I would like all of the components my project uses, i.e. `angular.js`, `jquery.js`, and so forth, to be in `scripts.js`. Is it easy to reconfigure the GruntFile to do so? Or is this not done by default for a practical reason?

Comment: Yes I have the same question, why is this left as a default? What happens if you use common CDNs, does that mean they shouldn't be concatenated? Also what about things like modernizr? They cannot be concatenated either because it needs to be at the top of the page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is easy to configure. Just add the vendors scripts in the sources you pass the grunt `concat` task.

```
// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    dist: {
      src: ['vendors/**/*.js', 'scripts/**/*.js'],
      dest: 'built.js'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm curious: I know browserify does concatenation based on require statments.  Is this an overlap of functionality with grunt, or are there different use-cases?

Comment: Well, Grunt is simply a task runner. It has no understanding whatsoever of concatenation or browserify. The concatenation task is a Grunt plugin. A Grunt plugin is simply a registered task you can call from your command line. So, with Browserify, you'd simply use the browserify grunt plugin and add it to your workflow - and then you won't need any concatenation task. For my part, I never use concat task as I use RequireJs and it handle concatenation itself via his Grunt plugin.

Comment: In case that there are some dependencies in the vendor (for example, BackboneJS depends on Underscore), how can I concat all of them without specifying concat order manually?

Comment: @truongnguyen1912 use a dependency/module system. Webpack, Browserify, Require.js, etc etc